# How to improve this Access SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a query here which does what it is supposed to but I'm wondering if it is possible to make it more efficient *without* splitting it into 2 separate queries.

```
SELECT [Full UO Code] FROM HPP_MD
WHERE LEFT([Full UO Code],5) In 
(SELECT IIF([Building]="Site" AND 
([Function Name_Usage Type]<>"Property" AND 
[Function Name_Usage Type]<>"Undeveloped Land"),[Business Entity],"") As Test 
FROM HPP_MD);
```

This is just a simple Access query that I'm playing with. It is easy to get the results I require if I run the subquery as a 'create table' query and then run a second query against that new table to get the required data.

I created the query/subquery out of curiosity to see how it worked but it is pretty slow and I'm wondering if anything can be done to increase efficiency. Is creating a temporary column the correct thing to do here? I couldn't quite conceive of another way of doing this.

Any thoughts? I know the column headers are pretty atrocious but this was just a quick table I imported into Access and I couldn't be buggered to change the names in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if the IN always fails if the big `AND` comes out false. That's assuming `[Full UO Code]` is never the empty string, which may be wrong. But if I'm correct, you can get rid of the `IIF`, which basically can't be optimized, into a `WHERE`

```
/* ... IN */
(SELECT [Business Entity] FROM HPP_MD 
 WHERE 
 [Building]="Site" AND 
   ([Function Name_Usage Type]<>"Property" AND 
   [Function Name_Usage Type]<>"Undeveloped Land")
```

If this is correct so far, you may be able to rewrite the subquery into a self-join. That may or may not be faster. In any case, `[Building]` and `[Function Name_Usage Type]` should be indexed.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm so used to writing IF statements that it didn't occur to me to use this approach. I'll have another play!